# pure virtual template functions in a template class

Tags: class, function, templates, pure-virtual

So my instructor handed out some code that I believe does not work at all and I want to get some clarification on it. He used this in his hand out notes (it implies that this is correct).

```
template<class T>
class State
{
public:
    virtual void Enter(T*)=0;
    virtual void Execute(T*)=0;
    virtual void Exit(T*)=0;
    virtual ~State(){};
};
```

I can see what he is trying to do but I believe the compiler will not like it at all.
Can anyone help explain why this does or does not work.

Comment: Why do you think it won't work?

Answer (score 2):

This should work as none of the member functions are not template member functions.  The base class arguments can be deduced at compile-time, and the actual function to call can still be determined at runtime.

If you had this:

```
class Foo
{
    template< typename T > virtual void Bar( T * ) = 0;
};
```

You would have problems as there is no way to generate functions to handle all the potential types that may be passed into this function at compile time.